# Dynamic UILabel not working in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that can accept strings of variable lengths. The label should expand to accept whatever  length string it is given. I have this working in iOS7 but in iOS8, the label is single line and text is truncated when the text is too long. Number of lines is set to 0. Here is my code that works in iOS7:

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {

    [_theLabel setText:[_txtLabel text]];

    CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(_theLabel.frame.size.width, 9999);
    NSDictionary *attributesDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[_txtLabel text] attributes:attributesDict];
    CGRect requireHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

    if(requireHeight.size.width > _theLabel.frame.size.width){
        requireHeight = CGRectMake(0, 0, _theLabel.frame.size.width, requireHeight.size.height);
    }

    CGRect newFrame = _theLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = requireHeight.size.height;
    [self.theLabel setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

Any suggestions for what has changed in iOS8? Thanks!

Comment: With auto layout this can be achieved without any line of code. Did you try calling `[label setNeedsLayout]` after setting the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do dynamic `UILabel` height like this:

```
-(UILabel*)setupTitleLabelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UILabel *lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    lbl_title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    lbl_title.numberOfLines = 0;

    lbl_title.text = title;

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(lbl_title.frame.size.width, 9999);
    CGSize expectedSize = [lbl_title sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
    lbl_title.frame = CGRectMake(lbl_title.frame.origin.x, lbl_title.frame.origin.y, lbl_title.frame.size.width, expectedSize.height);

    return lbl_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, however, this code only works in iOS7 or less. In iOS8 the label is one line and the text is truncated.

Comment: I'm using this code in iOS8, haven't had any problems with it